# Вывод русских символов в программе C++

Tags: c++

Привет всем. Есть программа для игры и шрифты для вывода текста в меню берутся из самой игры, шрифты эти поддерживают русский язык точно, я проверял.

Когда я делаю какой-то пункт меню например, у меня вместо русских букв "каракули", а англ отображаются нормально. В чем может быть проблема? Уже даже wchar пробовал такой код:

```
const wchar_t str[] = L"wcstombs привет";
        char buffer[32];
        int ret;

        //printf("wchar_t string: %ls \n", str);

        ret = wcstombs(buffer, str, sizeof(buffer));
        if (ret == 32) buffer[31] = '\0';
        //if (ret) printf("multibyte string: %s \n", buffer);
```

И все равно wcstombs отображается, а "привет" нет. Писать названия пунктов меню нужно именно в char*. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Возможно поможет добавить строчку `setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");` куда-нибудь в начало программы.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй в начале ф-ции main написать - setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

Answer (score 1):

Если писать названия пунктов меню нужно именно в char*, и при этом поддерживаются русские шрифты, у вас банально не совпадают кодировки. С большой вероятностью нужно передавать строки в utf8, для этого можно использовать префикс u в c++11: `u"привет"`. Если не поможет, я бы рекомендовал скинуть строку с русским текстом в отдельный файл, затем читать её из файла и передавать дальше. При этом можно поэкспериментировать с различными кодировками в файле, и подобрать нужную. Или можно менять кодировки исходников, но это не надёжно.

Возможно, стоит полазить в исходниках, может быть где-то написано, какая кодировка нужна.

Ну и `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` действительно лишним не должен быть.